# jquery fadeTo chain not working

Tags: jquery

The first part of my chains tied to the `.click()` events: `slideDown()` works however the `fadeTo()` portion does not.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#contact').click(function() 
    {

        $('#contact_box').remove();

        $('.menu_item_content').prepend('<div class="menu_box" id="contact_box">Contact INFO goes in this box.</div>');

        $('#contact_box').slideDown('slow', function()
        {
            $(this).fadeTo( 'slow', 1, function()
            {
            });
        });

    });

    $('#about').click(function() 
    {

        $('#about_box').remove();

        $('.menu_item_content').prepend('<div class="menu_box" id="about_box">About info goes in this box.</div>');

        $('#about_box').slideDown('slow', function()
        {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1, function()
            {
            });
        });
    });

    $('#twitter').click(function() 
    {

        $('#twitter_box').remove();

        $('.menu_item_content').prepend('<div class="menu_box" id="twitter_box">Twitter</div>');

        $('#twitter_box').slideDown('slow', function()
        {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1, function()
            {
            });
        });
    });


    //
    //remove single items
    //
    $(".menu_item_content").delegate("#contact_box", "click", function()
    { 
        $(this).remove();
        //$('#contact_box').remove(); 
    }); 


    $(".menu_item_content").delegate("#about_box", "click", function()
    {
        $(this).remove();
        //$('#about_box').remove(); 
    });

    $(".menu_item_content").delegate("#twitter_box", "click", function()
    {
        $(this).remove();
        //$('#twitter_box').remove();   
    });
});




</script>

<style>

.menu_item
{
    position:relative;

    display:inline;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:20px;
}
.menu_spacer
{
    display:inline;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:45px;
}

.menu_box
{
    display:none;
}

</style>

<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_items">
        <div class="menu_item" id="contact">CONTACT</div>
        <div class="menu_spacer">/</div>
        <div class="menu_item" id="about">ABOUT</div>
        <div class="menu_spacer">/</div>
        <div class="menu_item" id="twitter">TWITTER</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu_item_content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> it does not work

is maybe the worst of all error descriptions. However, what do you expect to happen here?

```
$('#twitter_box').slideDown('slow', function()
    {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1, function()
        {
        });
    });
```

This will slide down `#twitter_box` and after that, it will fade it to `opacity 1` (100%) which it already should be. `.slideDown()` will show an element (100% opacity), conclusion: `.fadeTo()` trys to fade from 100% to 100% = no effect at all.

`.fadeTo()` expects a value from `0.01` to `1.00`.

Comment: Well I am not sure how much cleared I can be than that the `fadeTo()` part of the chain isn't fadingTo... This code is copied from another functional page of mine where the element fades in as it slides down.

I tried switching it so the `fadeTo()` is triggered first then the `slideDown()` but in that case the `slideDown()` does not fire.

Comment: @jAndy +1 - although `.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, callback] )` expects an opacity value between 0 (not 0.01) and 1, as per [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)